# How to enter datetime values in python selenium datepicker?

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker

I have the page to enter datetime, I have the datetime value as string, I am passing that to through the find_element_by_xpath, I am getting error
This is my xpath

[image]

I have the value in string variable

```
value = '1980-06-30T00:00:00Z'
```

I use the code

```
xpath = '//*[@id="main-panel"]/div/app-manual-update/div/div/form/div[36]/div/input'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys(value);
```

I get

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.61)
```

HTML
[image: ![enter image description here]

How to pass the datetime value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JS, like below :

```
from datetime import datetime
today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
date= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id="main-panel"]/div/app-manual-update/div/div/form/div[36]/div/input")))
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '2021-06-30T00:00:00Z')", date)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` also make sure to not click on date picker, it **will directly input** the **values** in **input field.**

Comment: Thanks for that, It ran without error, but value not passed to the inputbox

Comment: I need to see the HTML, is page url public ?

Comment: added the html in my question

Comment: A input tag must be there in the HTML, for this date picker, please share that. Something like that `<input type="date" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i5" max="2071-01-01" data-initial-value="">`

Comment: yeah, updated sorry

Comment: looks like the value is there in the html, but not displaying

Comment: I think I've got it,  see that `app-datetimepicker` that has a value `attribute` You need to follow that pattern. like `2021-06-30T00:00:00Z`

Comment: may I know how to do that pls?

Comment: try this `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '2021-06-30T00:00:00Z')", date)`

Comment: yeah that worked

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can use `arguments[0].value` also to set attribute value.

**HTML**:

[image]

**Code**:

```
date = wd.find_element_by_id("dobundefined")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '1980-06-30T00:00:00Z';", date)
```